# Cloud pages internal notification to different email addresses based on form data

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, cloudpagesurl, sfmcadmin

Hello All: I have a smart capture form in a landing page and want to notify email address 1 if Radio button 1 is selected or email address 2 if Radio button 2 is selected on form submission.

Current impelementation:

1. Added a hidden attribute "SubscriberKey" on the form that has an email address attached to it in the "All subscribers" list
2. Form pushes data to a sendable DE
3. Journey is checking for DE rows in point 2 and triggering an email activity to the subscriberkey's email

Can any of you please guide me on the approach/ solution to route the emails to different addresses based on form data? Thanks in advance

Comment: Your approach makes sense, the only thing I'd recommend is to not have the subscriber key in a hidden field. Instead have the processing page (or processing section of your code) do a look up to retrieve the needed information. I say that b/c while the subscriber key is hidden from the form, it's not hidden in the code (View Source).

Comment: Thanks for the response Eduardo, great point! I will update the implementation. I am hitting a roadblock with this requirement where I am not able to achieve the conditional email based on radio button selection since there is only 1 subscriberkey field and I don't think I am able to update the data extension data based on the selection.

Comment: If you share some of that code in your post, I can try and help identify where things might be wrong.

Comment: Eduardo, appreciate the help!!
I am not able to redirect to the Thank You page. I tried redirectToURL = %%==(cloudpagesURL('thank_you_page',@email,'email'))==%% var scFormLoaded = function () { window.ScForm.init({"gearID":"xxx","smartCaptureFormID":123,"sourceKey":ABC123","source":"dataExtension","triggeredSend":"","confirmationMessage":"<div style=\"text-align: center;\">\n Thank you.</div>","buttonText":"Submit","formStyling":{"onSubmitShouldGotoUrl":true,"onSubmitGotoUrlType":2,"onSubmitGotoUrl":"thank_you_page"}); };

Comment: The first parameter of CloudPagesURL is the numeric ID of the page. That might be your problem there. Check out The AMPscript Guide - https://ampscript.guide/cloudpagesurl/